# How to find a content of the default TaskScheduler in a dump of a .NET application?

Tags: .net, task, windbg, dump, sos

I am trying to find a content of the default `TaskScheduler` in a dump of a `.NET application`. How I can do that?

An application was hung.

[image: application was hung]

I need to make sure that the default scheduler contains a `delayed task` with a certain `delegate`.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: I think he's talking about the [TaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the TaskScheduler class. Specifically about the [TaskScheduler.Default Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.default(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is it a regular `.dmp`? Try opening it in Visual Studio. Given sufficient symbols, the debugger should be able to display an overview of tasks (Debug -> Windows -> Tasks). If it's a partial dump or you have no symbols, this will not work, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find the method table of the TaskScheduler

```
0:025> .loadby sos clr
0:025> .symfix c:\debug\symbols
0:025> !name2ee mscorlib.dll System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler
Module:      000007feeea11000
Assembly:    mscorlib.dll
Token:       000000000200052e
MethodTable: 000007feef0a8ab0
EEClass:     000007feeebde1a8
Name:        System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler
```

Then, dump the heap to find some objects of that type. Note that I'm using String here, since I don't have an application with a TaskScheduler available.

```
0:025> !dumpheap -mt <MethodTable>
```

Now that you have some objects, just dump one of them.

```
0:025> !do 00000000126ed548 
Name:        System.String
MethodTable: 000007feef0bda88
EEClass:     000007feeea16a08
Size:        34(0x22) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
String:      100%
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007feef0c03d0  4000243        8         System.Int32  1 instance                4 m_stringLength
000007feef0bec38  4000244        c          System.Char  1 instance               31 m_firstChar
000007feef0bda88  4000248       80        System.String  0   shared           static Empty
```

Notice the `shared` (static) property `Empty` for the String. You should get something similar in TaskScheduler for the static property `Default`.

As you can see, you can see nothing. That's why you need the [SOSEX](http://www.stevestechspot.com/) extension and do a `!mdt System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler`.

```
0:025> !mdt System.String
System.String
[...]
    [s]Empty: string
        AppDomain 'Test.exe' (0000000001d73470): 0000000011fc1420[System.String] STRVAL=
```

Comment: This answer is unlikely to yield any results relevant to the question. The tasks scheduled by `TaskScheduler.Default` aren't found in any instance properties of the class in most implementations (specifically not `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`). An actual answer is a lot more involved.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: as mentioned in the comments, that's what he wanted. If it doesn't solve the problem, that's a different story. If you know a better answer, I'd be glad to hear about it. Feel free to downvote.